# to find week begin date and week end date

Tags: hive, db2

i have a to the find week start date and end date for each date.

for eg:
[image]

is it possible to achieve in IBM db2 and Hadoop ?
available fields are date and week id

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DAYOFWEEK_ISO function (which returns the day of week of a date, where 1 = Monday):

```
with s (dt) as (
    values date('2021-10-27')
)
select
    dt,
    dt - dayofweek_iso(dt) + 1 days as beginning_dt,
    dt - dayofweek_iso(dt) + 7 days as end_dt
from s;


DT         BEGINNING_DT END_DT    
---------- ------------ ----------
10/27/2021 10/25/2021   10/31/2021

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thanks. But can I have this done using dt or week fields alone?

Comment: This **is done** using the `dt` column only.

Comment: I want an expression which can be used in db2 and hive simultaneously

Comment: You must create some functions in Db2 database to have an ability use the same query in both databases. Do you have such an ability? Does the `DATE_FORMAT (some_date, 'u')` hive function return the corresponding week day number for the given `some_date` parameter based on `Monday=1`?

Comment: can you give the query to check?

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATE_FORMAT (P_TS TIMESTAMP, P_FORMAT VARCHAR (254))
RETURNS VARCHAR (254)
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
CONTAINS SQL
RETURN CASE P_FORMAT WHEN 'u' THEN DAYOFWEEK_ISO (P_TS) ELSE TO_CHAR (P_TS, P_FORMAT) END;`

Comment: this doesnt work in hive

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE` must be run in a Db2 database, not in hive. Again, check if `DATE_FORMAT (some_date, 'u')` returns expected week day number in hive.